# Replacing WordPress Icons (menu,icons32, etc)?

Tags: php, jquery, javascript, html, icon

I want to replace wordpress admin sprites. I recreated the images and looked answrs for icon replacement using jquery and simply with CSS BUT what about ones link icons32-2x.png where I can't find the CSS?

So I am trying to figure out a simple way to redirect the wordpress admin and includes folder to use my new icons INDIVIDUALLY.

Again this is just not for custom post type icons but all.

Basically I think through jQuery using replaceWith new icon but how can I replace an image if I don't know where its called in CSS (i.e. retina images) so I need a resolution to direct specific images in admin wp-admin and wp-includes folder.

- mydomain.com/wordpress/wp-admin/images/
- mydomain.com/wordpress/wp-inlcudes/images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS is in `wp-admin/css/colors-classic.css` and `wp-admin/css/colors-fresh.css` and the `min` versions of those, including the `icons32-2x.png` ones. I can see them when I `grep` the directory. For example, `wp-admin/css/colors-classic.css:2162`.

The images themselves are in `wp-admin/images`, as you can see from the style rules, but you should not be hacking/replacing those. They will be overwritten when you update WordPress.

I don't see the need for Javascript at all. Y[ou can register stylesheets for the backend.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts) That should be all you need.

Comment: If the icons are in a plugin they won't be overwritten

Comment: I was talking about the default icons. If you aren't going to be altering those default icons you don't need to know where they are (Your question is a bit confusing but is sounds like you want to know where to find some of those images). Just load your stylesheet and override the appropriate rules.

Comment: ok I can't overwrite them in the stylesheet if its retina images (ex of retina image - mydomain/wp-admin/images/list-2x.png) only popup up based on the browser. How can I change that image in css?

Comment: "I can't overwrite them in the stylesheet" combined with "How can I change that image in css?" _is contradictory_. What are you talking about? Also, [I am pretty sure you can target retina displays in a stylesheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955959/setting-specific-stylesheet-for-retina-displays).

Comment: sorry ok I got you,  I was not thinking at all I had to do is copy color-fresh.css for the css it has the media queries there already.